# Intercepting a console.log created by a node_module to display in a toast

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to use a console.log() created from within a node_module to display a toast on screen for the user.

I have my toasts working. I'm just not sure how to capture the log message since it is not being created from my personal code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

WARNING: This is extremely bad practice. It is not recommended to change the behavior of a native function especially not `console.log`.

That being said you can technically intercept logs by redefining the log function and then using console.info to still log things.

```js
console.log = function(...args) {
   alert("logged")
   console.info(...args);
}
```

I recommend forking the NPM package instead and implementing your own logic.

Comment: Thank you I was hoping that wasn't the answer but it seemed like the only way to go.

Comment: Be mindful that forking and implementing some logic without creating a PR to get it merged back in (and while it remains unmerged) means that you must maintain the code to ensure that it works for you.